# Can't get e.preventDefault to work with React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that looks like this:

```
const App = (): ReactElement => {
    
    const submitFeedbackHandler = (e: FormEvent): void => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // ...
    }

    return <>
        <form onSubmit={submitFeedbackHandler}>
            // ...
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </>

}
```

Problem is, no matter how I try to call `submitFeedbackHandler` from `onSubmit` it doesn't work. I tried `onSubmit={(e) => submitFeedbackHandler(e)}`, but no luck either. How can I get this to work so that I can do `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Does the page reload upon submit? Do you get any typecheck error? Are ```FormEvent``` & ```ReactElement``` imported?

Comment: Yes, the page reloads en no errors, and yes FormEvent and ReactElement are imported. The function `submitFeedbackHandler` is just not called at all when the form submits.

Comment: That's odd. It should work as expected. Can you show the whole component you're working? Maybe there's something in your code that you didn't show preventing the event to dispatch.

Comment: I found the problem. I had added `required` to some inputs in the form. Oddly enough, this stops `onSubmit` completely from being called. Even simply calling `() => console.log('onSubmit!')` didn't work, so I removed all the required tags from the inputs within the forms and it works fine now. I'll do validation of empty fields myself in that case instead of relying on the `required` tag on inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give some headache to inexperienced React developers like myself, so here's the answer to the problem:

I had added the `required` tag to some inputs in the form. Oddly enough, this stops `onSubmit` completely from being called. Even simply calling `onSubmit = {() => console.log('onSubmit!')}` didn't work, so I removed all the required tags from the inputs within the form and it works fine now. I'll do validation of empty fields myself in that case instead of relying on the required tag on inputs.

I think it has to do with controlled and uncontrolled components in React. Will do further research to see exactly what causes this. Thank you @Julius Guevarra for your help.